# Different CSS for homepage

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Ok, based on the answer [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/css-file-and-page-templates?replies=10) by traitadmin (scroll down) I am trying to display different CSS for my front page and one for all other pages.

Previously, my body tag looked like this:

```
<body <?php  body_class() ?>>
```

Now, I have edited it to look like this:

```
<body <?php if (is_home()) { ?> id="home"<?php } else { ?> body_class()<?php } ?> >
```

Also I have put new stylesheets in my enqueue, and all styles for the homepage now have `#home` in front of them.

However, there is no style at all now and my site broke down entirely, for all pages.

I think I may need `body_class()` also for the homepage. But how I can edit this code so that it works?

Comment: does body_class() add an id too or just a class?

Comment: I think you need to echo that `id="home"` out

Comment: why not put your home page in a different <div> tag and then create the css for the home page in that <div>?

Comment: wait im trying something. maybe I can use that body_class('home') in an if statement to check if the current page is home. Lemme try this!

Comment: Why not check to see if is the home page then actually include a another .css file that has a high priority than your standard css file?

Comment: Ok my own suggestion didn't work. @Pitchinnate, that sounds interesting! How would I do that?

Comment: @Forza see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would actually be this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<?php if (is_home()) {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">'
} ?>
```

Rules in home.css should have a high priority than main.css. So with this if main.css has this:

```
body { background-color: white; }
```

and home.css has this:

```
body { background-color: blue; }
```

Since home.css is linked after main.css the rule in home.css will take priority and the background will be blue. This way you can only overwrite the styles you need to and all the other styles will still apply.

In your case after your other `wp_register_style()` just add an if test and then register another style.

```
if (is_home()) {
    wp_register_style('home-style',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/stylesheets/home.css');
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I want to load stylesheets like this. I have loaded my styles in enqueue.php where I can set priority. See: http://piclair.com/data/4md89.jpg I think I can't set priority to stylesheets if I load them this way?

Comment: Sure you could after the code you show in that image just have an if test to see if it is the homepage then add another `wp_register_style()` that loads the home.css

Comment: See this: http://piclair.com/data/ccry8.jpg This breaks my site for some reason, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: Your comment about wp_register_style() solved my problem in this case. Thank you pitchinannate! If you can edit your answer so it contains wp_register_style() solution then I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a wordpress code so here goes:
In the head:

```
<?php if (is_home()) {
    // loading the stylesheet if it is the homepage
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">'
} else {
    // loading the other stylesheet if it is not the homepage
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="other.css">'
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, WordPress adds two classes to the body tag: on the front page (`is_front_page()`) the `home` class is added, and on the home page (`is_home()`) the `blog` class is added. So, in your main CSS file, you can use the body class as follows:

```
#mydiv {background:green;}
.home #mydiv {background:blue;}
.blog #mydiv {background:red;}
```